# How can I see the results in the problem browser in CPLEX ILOG?

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running a model in CPLEX OPL. I am not getting any results in the problem browser. I run the code on another computer and there is no problem and I see the results in the problem browser. I've checked the display settings and can't find any problems.

Normally I can see the parameters and the solution here. I tried reinstalling CPLEX but that did not help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE you could do the following:

Show view / Problem browser

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. I could turn the problem browser on and off. My actual problem is I could not see anything when I turn it on. There is nothing in the problem browser area. I get an optimal solution for the problem but in the problem browser section I cant see any data, any decision variables and any decision expressions.. By the way, I also could filter the problem browser in order to get the data I need.. Thank you.

Comment: Then you can tr to display your results in postprocessing . https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooprepostprocessing.mod